# Correct syntax for SQL Query with XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

My DataXML looks like this

```
<TestResults>    
<MethodResult>
X
X
<StepResult name="BluetoothERROR">
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
<StepResult name="FLOWERROR1">
        <Number value="-100" />
      </ActualValue>
X
X
<StepResult name="PowerOffError">
X
X
X
    </StepResult>
  </MethodResult>
</TestResults>
```

Where X means other instances of StepResult with different Name like BluetoothError or PowerOffError. Assume that the other StepResults can have similar outputs as the "FLOWERROR1".

I am particularly interested in StepResult with name "FlowError1" and I would like to return the Number value of -100.

I have tried this line of code and it did not work and only shows Nulls.

```
f.ResultXML.value('(/TestResults/MethodResult/StepResult/ActualValue/Number/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') As "Actual Value"
```

What should I have done instead?

Comment: Should ActualValue comes after Number in your XML path?

Answer (score 0):

You can to filter nodes by the name and return the first matching node' value:

```
select @data.value('(TestResults/MethodResult/StepResult[@name="FLOWERROR1"]/ActualValue/Number)[1]/@value', 'int')
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1c3128613f30c2770b148396147e454d)

See [`Introduction to Using XPath Queries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sqlxml-annotated-xsd-schemas-xpath-queries/introduction-to-using-xpath-queries-sqlxml-4-0?view=sql-server-2017) and [`XQuery Language Reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: How did you know the OP was using _SQL Server_ when it wasn't in the question tags?

Comment: @Abra good question, his example query looks very much like Sql Server to me

Comment: My mistake, yes it is SQL Server.